# which spring jar file is required jstl tags

Tags: java, spring, jstl

In have xml file with

```
 <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

which spring jar file is required for it

Comment: It's not Spring. It's JSTL. For more detail about downloading and installing see our wiki page which appears when you hover the `[jstl]` tag and click the *info* link: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None, you can download it manually from [jstl.java.net](http://jstl.java.net/) or [download.java.net/maven](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar).

Alternatively if you're using a build system such as `Apache Maven` you can get it using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That's an `Apache Maven` type of dependency. If you're not using it I suggest using the provided download link (or try direct link from [java2s](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/jstl.jar.zip)).

Comment: I'm curious why you expected that the OP knows how to use Maven. S/he has nowhere mentioned/tagged it. The download link is by the way outdated.

Comment: @BalusC Diversity/habit :) The download link have now been updated, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

It is part of the [Apache Taglibs](http://tomcat.apache.org/taglibs/standard/) ?